# Confirm box and change form action on yes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, confirm

I have problem with this script

```
$("#izmene_lica").click(function () {
var ask = window.confirm("Da li ste sigurni da želite da sačuvate ove podatke?");
if (ask) {
     $('#odabir').attr('action', 'proces_hr.php'); //#odabir is id of my form
} else {
    return false;
}
});
```

It sometimes work, sometimes not. In `IE` almost never work. What i need is popup window that will ask for confirmation and if it is confirmed form action should change. I tried many ways, in IE i cant make it work. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: And would `#izmene_lica` be a button inside the `#odabir` form by any chance ?

Comment: please provide your html?

Comment: My html is about whole page. Yes `#izmene_lica` is submit inside my form.

Comment: use on() method in jquery.  something like $("#izmene_lica").on("click" function () { }); and replace prop instead of attr.

Comment: I tried with attr first, same result. I get my question (confirm window) but after clicking on yes nothing happens.

Comment: izmene_lica where it is inside the form ah?

Comment: i answered that. Yes it is inside form.

Comment: what error you got on console? when nothing happened on event?

Comment: Nothing. No error. Just page blink as it was submitet but nothihg happens.

Comment: it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/NPRXu/

Comment: it add the attr action also works fine then what issue u have?

Comment: It should go to procesing page after confirmation, and there do sometnihg and redirect back to page with form but with processed data.   And nothing happens. It just stay on this page.

Comment: i added this ` var action =  $("#odabir").attr('action');
        alert(action); ` after adding action param and i get proces_hr.php as i should. But i remained on page with form.

Answer (score 0):

IE sometimes behaves weirdly. Besides setting `return false` will do the follwing things. It will call [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) action of the handler (`click()` in this case) and [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) which will prevent the events bubbling up the DOM.

try updating your code with snippet.

```
$("#izmene_lica").click(function (e) {
  var ask = window.confirm("Da li ste sigurni da želite da sačuvate ove podatke?");
  if (ask) {
   $('#odabir').attr('action', 'proces_hr.php');
  } else {
   e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

As one of your comments that `#izmene_lica` is your submit button. you can also bind it with your `submit()` handler. Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/zoyoqena/2/edit).